# How to make vim print the key i pressed directly when i have mapped this key with another one?

Tags: vim

When I map 2 keys together for example <Tab><Space> and press the first one Vim will first wait to see if i press Space before printing the tabulation.

I would like to know if it is possible to make vim print the tabulation first and then waiting for an eventual Space key for mapping.

Thank You !

Comment: what should Vim do, if you don't press Space? Delete the Tab again?

Comment: It is not possible.